# How to structure a Visual Studio project for the data access layer

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I currently have a project that uses various DB access technologies mainly for showcasing or for demos.

Currently we have:

```
Namespace App.Data (App.Data.dll)
    Folder NHibernate
    Folder EntityFramework
    Folder LinqToSql
```

The above structure is ok as we only use Sql Server as the DB.  But going forward we will be including Oracle, MySql etc.

So what would be a better structure with this in mind?

I thought about:

```
Namespace App.Data.SqlServer (App.Data.SqlServer.dll)
    Folder NHibernate
    Folder EntityFramework
    Folder LinqToSql
```

Or would it just be better to have separate assemblies for each database and access technology?:

```
Namespace App.Data.SqlServer.NHibernate (App.Data.SqlServer.NHibernate.dll)
Namespace App.Data.SqlServer.EntityFramework(App.Data.SqlServer.EntityFramework.dll)
Namespace App.Data.Oracle.NHibernate (App.Data.Oracle.NHibernate.dll)
Namespace App.Data.MySql.NHibernate (App.Data.MySql.Oracle.dll)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would almost do the opposite, and group by DAO implementation technologies.

```
    - Namespace App.Data
       -NHibernate
         - SQLServer
         - Oracle
       -EntityFramework
         - SQLServer
         - Oracle
```

And from there you could split DLLs if it is nessessary.  So you could either have 2 dlls, or 4 however you see fit.